# Comparing strings with localeCompare vs ===?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran into a pretty strange issue with my latest JS project. I usually compare strings using `===` but when comparing the string properties of two of different objects I got false even though they were the exact same strings. I tested this in my Node.js interpreter by doing the following:

```
> x = {str: 'hello'}
{ str: 'hello' }
> y = {str: 'hello'}
{ str: 'hello' }
> y.str === x.str
true
```

So I couldnt figure out why my code wasnt working. But when I switch from using `===` to `str1.localeCompare` BOOM, it works. Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: `localeCompare` takes the current locale into account. `===` takes the raw bytes into account.

Comment: That picture doesn't show the problem.

Comment: @James But it is a very nice picture

Answer (score 25):

`===` looks for exactly the same bytes in the strings.

`.localeCompare()` allows for the fact that you may want to ignore certain differences in the strings (such as puncutation or diacriticals or case) and still allow them to compare the same or you want to ignore certain differences when deciding which string is before the other.  And, it provides lots of options to control what comparison features are or are not used.

If you read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for `string.prototype.localeCompare()`, you can see a whole bunch of options you can pass in to control how the compare works.  On a plain ascii string with no special characters in it that are all the same case, you are unlikely to see a difference, but start getting into diacriticals or case issues and `localCompare()` has both more features and more options to control the comparison.

Some of the options available for controlling the comparison:

1. numeric collation
2. diacritical sensitivity
3. ability to ignore punctuation
4. case first
5. control whether upper or lower case compares first

In addition, `localeCompare()` returns a value (negative, 0 or positive) that is perfectly aligned to use with a `.sort()` callback.

Comment: Why wouldn't the two strings have the same bytes?

Comment: @DanielKobe - Somewhat by definition, because `===` was not saying the OP's two strings where the same, they were apparently not the same.  But, since `localeCompare()` was saying they were the same, then the two strings differed only in ways that `localeCompare()` doesn't care about.  The OP's question is about what is different between `===` and `localeCompare()` and that's what I answered in my question.