# sort value not coming where i have used the sort in map

Tags: javascript

I tried below code
var data =

```
[{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},
        {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},
        {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];     
var names = data.map(s=>s.name.sort());
console.log(names);
```

ERROR:`TypeError: s.name.sort is not a function`.

*But expecting the output is `["karthik","ramu", "ravi"]`*

Comment: `s.name` is a `string` while you are able to use `.sort` only on arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var names = data.map(s=>s.name).sort(); //just move the sort out
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "ramu",
    "id": "719",
    "gmail": "ramu@gmail.com",
    "ph": 988989898,
    "points": 36
  },
  {
    "name": "ravi",
    "id": "445",
    "gmail": "ravi@gmail.com",
    "ph": 4554545454,
    "points": 122
  },
  {
    "name": "karthik",
    "id": "866",
    "gmail": "karthik@gmail.com",
    "ph": 2332233232,
    "points": 25
  }
];
//var names = data.map(s=>s.name).sort(); //just move the sort out
var names = data.map(s => s.name).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); //used localeCompare instead of simple sort

console.log(names);
```

Comment: @ramu Use localecompare instead of simple sort, there are some benefits check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489250/comparing-strings-with-localecompare-vs

Answer (score 4):

You have used the `sort` on a string, but it is applicable only on arrays.
You need first get only names, than use sort on the **array of names**.

Here you can omit the function passed into the `sort` and use just `.sort()`, but it will give you some more benefits.

```js
var data = [{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},      {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},      {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];    
        
var names = data.map(s => s.name).sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b));
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comment above, `s.name` is a string while you are able to use `.sort` function only on arrays.

To deal with that issue, you could firstly `map` given array to get just the `name` properties and **then** sort it.

```js
const a = [{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},
   {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},
   {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];    
        
const names = a.map((s) => s.name).sort();

console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 2):

Map first and then sort on array of names.

```js
var data = [{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},      {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},      {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];    

var names = data.map(s=>s.name);
var sorted = names.sort();
console.log(sorted );
```

Answer (score 2):

First you can map over your array so you just have the names in an array, which you can then `sort`.

Your code would look like the following:

```js
var list = [{
    "name": "ramu",
    "id": "719",
    "gmail": "ramu@gmail.com",
    "ph": 988989898,
    "points": 36
  },
  {
    "name": "ravi",
    "id": "445",
    "gmail": "ravi@gmail.com",
    "ph": 4554545454,
    "points": 122
  },
  {
    "name": "karthik",
    "id": "866",
    "gmail": "karthik@gmail.com",
    "ph": 2332233232,
    "points": 25
  }
];

var sortedNames = list.map(item => {
  return item.name;
}).sort();

console.log(sortedNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following code to get your Names Array -

```js
var data = [{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},
        {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},
        {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];

// Names Array Only
var namesArr = data.map(s => s.name).sort((a, b)=> a.localeCompare(b));
document.write('<pre>Names Array ==><br>' + JSON.stringify(namesArr) + '</pre>');
```

Also, JSON sorted by name if required -

```js
var data = [{"name":"ramu","id":"719","gmail":"ramu@gmail.com","ph":988989898,"points":36},
            {"name":"ravi","id":"445","gmail":"ravi@gmail.com","ph":4554545454,"points":122},
            {"name":"karthik","id":"866","gmail":"karthik@gmail.com","ph":2332233232,"points":25}];

// sort JSON by names
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
document.write('<pre>Sorted JSON by names ==><br>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```